# How to I get rid of or override vuetify's v-textarea bottom border?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to get rid of Vuetify's default underline in v-textarea without using flat and solo. This is my code:

```
    <v-textarea
      v-model="card.todo"
      placeholder="New item"
      class="text-area"
      auto-grow
      rows="1"
      row-height="10"
      @keyup="update_card"
    ></v-textarea>
```

and this is how it renders:

```
<div class="v-input__slot"><div class="v-text-field__slot"><textarea id="input-105" placeholder="New item" rows="1" style="height: 84px;"></textarea></div></div>
```

I believe it has to do with class="v-input__slot" because when I delete that line the underline goes away.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.v-input.v-textarea>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot:before {
    border: none;
}
```

just be aware that this will clear the border for all the `v-textarea`s , so use a class or id if you don't want that!

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. Even if I would another style attribute on it, it doesn't change the style of the textarea, so doesn't look like it's selecting the div.

Comment: can you make a pen of your code and let me see what is the problem ?

Comment: Hey, take a look at the default style... that's the line I'm trying to hide: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=101

Comment: your pen is empty mate :)

Comment: Ah that's odd... my apologies. Please go here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textareas/#usage and click on their codepen.

Comment: check [this pen](https://codepen.io/devisshortfordevil/pen/oNzZKEg) and tell if you need anything else .

Comment: Nope, and it's the line in the default style I'm trying to override.

Comment: Unfortunately, your pen doesn't seem to work with my Vue app.

Answer (score 0):

add attr (variant='solo-filled') to the textarea tag

`<v-textarea variant='solo-filled'></v-textarea>`

You can Find More Information Here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textareas/